# Codeigniter regexp routing

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a problem with routing like this:

```
$route['(/[a-z]{2}/)'] = 'locale/somepage';
```

And in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(/[a-z]{2}/)$ /index.php/locale/somepage
```

I need replace first section of url (class or controller) and call an another controller. For example, I need to url as **/en/page** will call controller **locale**, but url need not be changed.

This code is not working. And if I try use only routes.php or only .htaccess, it not working too.
How I can make it work?

Comment: Check if what I answered fits your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've written your htaccess regexp rule wrong. You don't need to write it as a PHP regexp rule, try to rewrite it without the slash in your htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/page$ /index.php/locale/somepage
```

This will send any `http://mypage.com/en/page` to index.php/locale/somepage.

With that rule, CI will receive the url `index.php/locale/somepage`. At that point, CI will go to `routes.php` and will check if there are any rule to call a specific controller. If not, it'll try to go to a controller called `locale`, to load a method called `somepage`.

So, you don't need to use `routes.php` to modify again the apache url that you're receving to call another controller.